# Nodejs installing failure

Tags: node.js, nvm-windows

When ive trying to install lts nodejs using NVM ive got error

```
C:\Home\Self\dev\cv>nvm install 18
Downloading node.js version 18.16.0 (64-bit)...
Error while creating C:\Home\Self\Soft\nvm\v18.16.0\node.zip - open C:\Home\Self\Soft\nvm\v18.16.0\node.zip: The system cannot find the path specified.
Could not download node.js v18.16.0 64-bit executable.
```

Using system: win64

```
nvm arch
System Default: 64-bit.
Currently Configured: 64-bit.

nvm -v
1.1.10

nvm list
12.10.0
* 8.12.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
```

Help me pls